# How to use two models in asp.net mvc on a View?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two models and i am struggling to use them on my View for my Form. Any mate who can help me to clarify this better? My logic is as below:

```
// Two model class here.

    public class RoleViewAndFileViewModel
    {
        public RoleViewModel RoleViewModelData { get; set; }

        public FileViewModel FileViewModelData { get; set; }
    }


//View class
@using eNtsaRegistrationTraining.Models
@RoleViewAndFileViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Ttile = "Dashboard";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_HomeLayout.cshtml";
}
```

Comment: What problem are you having, exactly? Your code looks fine to me so far.

Comment: Aren't you suppose to declare model like `@model RoleViewAndFileViewModel`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a view, you declare your model like @model YourClassName

For exemple, if your model is a list of string, you declare like

```
@model List<string>
```

and then, you can use your model in your view like:

```
@foreach(string s in Model)
{
  <div> @s </div>
}
```

But, if in your case you need two type of object, you can add a class which contains as parameter your two objects and use it in your view as model like this :

```
namespace MyMVCapplication
{
 public class MyModelMV
 {
    public MyFirstClas MyFirstClassProp { get; set; }
    public MySecondClass MySecondClassProp { get; set; }
 }

 public class MyFirstClas
 {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }

 }
 public class MySecondClass
 {
    public double Width { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
 }
}
```

And in your view :

```
  @model MyModelMV
```

And than you can access to your objects like

```
<div>@Model.MyFirstClassProp.Name</div>
<div>@Model.MySecondClassProp.Code</div> 
...
...
```